# Как отобразить блок при вертикальном скролле БЕЗ JQuery?

Tags: html, css, css3

Задача банальна - отобразить нужную панельку на странице при скролле. Но сделать это каким угодно способом, кроме jquery. Если есть медиа запросы, которые позволяют отследить прокрутку, будет шикарно.

Comment: без  jq, если только на чистом jd... css  ничего подобного не умеет

Answer (score 0):

Решение на js:

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    if (window.pageYOffset > 150) {
         document.querySelector(".fixed").classList.add('visible')
    } else {
        document.querySelector(".fixed").classList.remove('visible')
    }
    //Когда оно должно быть "видимо", имеет класс visible
});
```